# How to receive notification with one signal when app is in background or closed

Tags: flutter, push-notification, flutter-dependencies, onesignal

I can only receive push notif when app is in foreground, followed instructions [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/service-extensions#android-notification-service-extension) and created a .java file in com.package.name now I have 2 files there MainActivity.java And NotificationServiceExtension.java
One signal version 3.4.2.
Also posted this on [github](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Flutter-SDK/issues/618)

Added this on my manifest

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationServiceExtension"
            android:value="com.bonfire.cdis.NotificationServiceExtension" />
```

Here is the error

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
D:\caps\cdis\android\app\src\main\java\com\bonfire\cdis\NotificationServiceExtension.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
            builder.setColor(new BigInteger("FF00FF00", 16).intValue());
                                 ^
  symbol:   class BigInteger
  location: class NotificationServiceExtension
D:\caps\cdis\android\app\src\main\java\com\bonfire\cdis\NotificationServiceExtension.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
            Spannable spannableTitle = new SpannableString(notification.getTitle());
            ^
  symbol:   class Spannable
  location: class NotificationServiceExtension
D:\caps\cdis\android\app\src\main\java\com\bonfire\cdis\NotificationServiceExtension.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
            Spannable spannableTitle = new SpannableString(notification.getTitle());
                                           ^
  symbol:   class SpannableString
  location: class NotificationServiceExtension
D:\caps\cdis\android\app\src\main\java\com\bonfire\cdis\NotificationServiceExtension.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
            spannableTitle.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),0,notification.getTitle().length(),0);
                                       ^
  symbol:   class ForegroundColorSpan
  location: class NotificationServiceExtension
D:\caps\cdis\android\app\src\main\java\com\bonfire\cdis\NotificationServiceExtension.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
            spannableTitle.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),0,notification.getTitle().length(),0);
                                                           ^
  symbol:   variable Color
  location: class NotificationServiceExtension
D:\caps\cdis\android\app\src\main\java\com\bonfire\cdis\NotificationServiceExtension.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
            Spannable spannableBody = new SpannableString(notification.getBody());
            ^
  symbol:   class Spannable
  location: class NotificationServiceExtension
D:\caps\cdis\android\app\src\main\java\com\bonfire\cdis\NotificationServiceExtension.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
            Spannable spannableBody = new SpannableString(notification.getBody());
                                          ^
  symbol:   class SpannableString
  location: class NotificationServiceExtension
D:\caps\cdis\android\app\src\main\java\com\bonfire\cdis\NotificationServiceExtension.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
            spannableBody.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE),0,notification.getBody().length(),0);
                                      ^
  symbol:   class ForegroundColorSpan
  location: class NotificationServiceExtension
D:\caps\cdis\android\app\src\main\java\com\bonfire\cdis\NotificationServiceExtension.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
            spannableBody.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE),0,notification.getBody().length(),0);
                                                          ^
  symbol:   variable Color
  location: class NotificationServiceExtension
9 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Comment this code and there will be no issues in background Notification Handling. This code is meant to be used for customisation.

```
  mutableNotification.setExtender(builder -> {
        // Sets the accent color to Green on Android 5+ devices.
        // Accent color controls icon and action buttons on Android 5+. Accent color does not change app title on Android 10+
        // builder.setColor(new BigInteger("FF00FF00", 16).intValue());
        // // Sets the notification Title to Red
        // Spannable spannableTitle = new SpannableString(notification.getTitle());
        // spannableTitle.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),0,notification.getTitle().length(),0);
        // builder.setContentTitle(spannableTitle);
        // // Sets the notification Body to Blue
        // Spannable spannableBody = new SpannableString(notification.getBody());
        // spannableBody.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE),0,notification.getBody().length(),0);
        // builder.setContentText(spannableBody);
        //Force remove push from Notification Center after 30 seconds
        builder.setTimeoutAfter(30000);
        return builder;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this imports

```
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.graphics.Color;
import java.math.BigInteger;
```

Comment: This one helped me to get the build done. Thanks

Comment: Then you can vote for this answer )